# Движение персонажа в координатной плоскости Python

Tags: python, разработка-игр

У меня вопрос, для решения которого код не обязателен (напишу сам). Хотя все-же был бы не против примеров. В общем, я делаю 2д игру с видом сверху. И я не знаю как реалитзовать движение под углом (по диагонали). То есть сейчас он, вроде как, приходит в ту точку что мне нужна, но он не делает этого кратчайшим маршрутом. Одно НО, он всетаки может двигаться по диагонали, но только под углом 45 градусов.
PS: Поясню, что я хочу узнать как мне считать скорость к отдельным координатным плоскостям, при этом, что-бы общая скорость движения сохранялась.

Вот пример моего кода сейчас:

```
# Движение к заданным координатам
def directional_movement(self, x_cord_direction, y_cord_direction):
while True:
    if self.X_Cord != x_cord_direction:
        if self.X_Cord < x_cord_direction:
            if x_cord_direction - self.X_Cord < self.Move_Speed / 100:
                self.X_Cord = x_cord_direction
            else:
                self.X_Cord += self.Move_Speed / 100
        else:
            if self.X_Cord - x_cord_direction < self.Move_Speed / 100:
                self.X_Cord = x_cord_direction
            else:
                self.X_Cord -= self.Move_Speed / 100
    if self.Y_Cord != y_cord_direction:
        if self.Y_Cord < y_cord_direction:
            if y_cord_direction - self.Y_Cord < self.Move_Speed / 100:
                self.Y_Cord = y_cord_direction
            else:
                self.Y_Cord += self.Move_Speed / 100
        else:
            if self.Y_Cord - y_cord_direction < self.Move_Speed / 100:
                self.Y_Cord = y_cord_direction
            else:
                self.Y_Cord -= self.Move_Speed / 100
    self.move_drawing_hit_box()
    if self.X_Cord == x_cord_direction and self.Y_Cord == y_cord_direction:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для движения по прямой достаточно будет посчитать угол и расстояние до объекта.
В вашем коде персонаж ходит только по узлам виртуальной сетки размером `self.Move_Speed / 100`

Кроме того, названия переменных `x_cord_direction` и `y_cord_direction` не соответствуют действительности и только вводят в заблуждение. На самом деле это координаты цели в которую должен переместиться объект.

```
# Движение к заданным координатам
def directional_movement(self, x_target, y_target):
while True:
    if self.X_Cord != x_target or self.Y_Cord != y_target:
        dx_target = x_target - self.X_Cord
        dy_target = y_target - self.Y_Cord

        # Направление к цели
        direction = math.atan2(dy_target, dx_target)

        # Расстояние до цели
        distance = math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)

        step = self.Move_Speed / 100

        if distance < step:
            self.X_Cord = x_target
            self.Y_Cord = y_target
        else:
            # Сместить каждую координату на соответствующую составляющую вектора движения в нужную сторону
            self.Y_Cord = self.Y_Cord + math.sin(direction) * step
            self.X_Cord = self.X_Cord + math.cos(direction) * step

    self.move_drawing_hit_box()
    if self.X_Cord == x_target and self.Y_Cord == y_target:
        break
```